# How to do error control for rejecting characters, spacing and extra decimal point?

Tags: c, error-handling

the program requires user to key in an initial value which allows for range between 0 to 1000 including decimal placing

how to create error control to reject characters, spacing, or additional decimal point placed such as 1.2.3? n loop itself to prompt user for new input

---

```
printf("Please enter initial velocity(in m/s) of ball when thrown vertically upwards: \n");
scanf("%lf%c",&v0,&rubbish);
printf("%f\n",v0);
printf("%c\n",rubbish);

/*error control for incorrect range of value entered*/
while (v0<0 || v0> 1000|| rubbish !='\n')
{
/*Ask user for correct value of velocity*/
v0='\n', rubbish="\n";
printf("\nIncorrect value keyed\n");
printf("Please enter again the initial velocity(in m/s) of ball when thrown vertically upwards: \n");
scanf("%lf",&v0);
scanf("%c",&rubbish);
printf("%f\n",v0);
printf("%c\n",rubbish);
```

### }

Comment: Is this a homework? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: i used a scanf function with a while loop, it can reject alphabets and values out of the range but when a value such as 1ewe2 is entered it will scan e last 2 and carry out the program...

Comment: Don't put info that explains your question in the comments. Update your question instead (click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7856769/edit)).

Comment: Are you trying to implement [`strtod()`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?strtod)?

Comment: you could see an example if you follow the link.

Comment: sry im new to c programming and have not learn this at all, so how to implement strtod() when i have to get keyed values?

Answer (score 1):

> how to implement strtod() when i have to get keyed values?

I understand it as: you'd like to get a double from a user (I understand "keyed" in your comment as "typed on keyboard"). With additional constraint that input line should not contain any other characters or extra decimals.

You could do it in two steps:

1. read line
2. parse double

#### read line from stdin

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fgets
#include <string.h> // strlen
// ...
char buf[BUFSIZ];
char *s = NULL;
if ((s = fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin)) == NULL || strlen(s) == (BUFSIZ-1)) {
  // can't read from stream or line is too long
  return -1; // return <0 from your function to indicate error to the caller
}
```

At this point `s` contains user input.

#### parse double using [`strtod()`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?strtod)

`strtod()` can detect many error conditions: overflow, underflow, empty strings, or leading non-whitespace characters can't be interpreted as a floating-point number. The interface might be confusing (and some corner cases changed between c89 and c99). You can peek and choose what conditions you'd like to detect and ignore others.

Here's an example that requires that the string contained only a number and optional leading, trailing whitespace and nothing else:

```
#include <ctype.h>  // isspace
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>   // HUGE_VAL
#include <stdlib.h> // strtod
// ...
int ret = 0;
char *endptr = NULL;
double d = 0.0; 
int save = errno; // save original value
errno = 0;        // clear  
if (out && // double *out (function parameter)
    !(((d = strtod(s, &endptr)) == 0.0 || d == HUGE_VAL || d == -HUGE_VAL) &&
    (str == endptr || errno == EINVAL || errno == ERANGE))) { 
  // `d` contains a number

  // check what left in the string
  while(isspace(*endptr))
    ++endptr; // skip whitespace

  if (*endptr == '\0')
    *out = d; // success
  else
    ret = -1; // error: non-whitespace encountered after the number
}
else 
  ret = -1; // error: can't read a number 
errno = save; // restore
return ret;
```